# Java LinkedList obtaining first element

Tags: java

I have an Java `LinkedList` which stores two values (code below).

I was wondering how i can obtain the first value only?

I have:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.add(number+" "+string);
```

I want to be able to just print out number from the list. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, note that by doing `list.add(number + " " + string)` **you're adding a single object**, namely the string formed by concatenating `number` and `string`.

That said, you could try something like this, to get the first part of the first element:

```
list.get(0).split(" ")[0]
```

---

Example:

```
int number = 17;
String string = "hello";

LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add(number+" "+string);


// Print number of first item:
System.out.println(list.get(0).split(" ")[0]);  // prints "17"
```

Comment: Yeah, but you are not accessing the original value, but a String representation thereof.

Comment: True. He says he wants to print out the number though, so I would assume the string representation is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The List does not store two values. It stores one Object, the String created by concatenating number with a space and the String.

If you want to access individual Objects, you should either use a Map instead of a List or create a custom Object that holds number and string:

a)

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new Hashmap<Integer, String>();
map.put(number, string);
```

b)

```
public class MyObject{
  private Number number;
  private String string;
  // + getters and setters
}
```

---

Also:

a) you should not use Non-generic Collections anymore. Generics were introduced 7 years ago, there should not be any reason not to use them these days.

So you should use this:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Or this:

```
LinkedList<MyCustomObject> list = new LinkedList<MyCustomObject>();
```

b) are you sure you want a `LinkedList`? In most cases, `ArrayList` is the general purpose `List` implementation. `LinkedList` performs better if you have many `add()` statements and don't know in advance how large your List will be, but `ArrayList` performs a lot better for random access.

Comment: Someone apparently wants the question answered literally, which I refuse to do. Answering the question literally would be giving bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the `number` only.

First get the object at index 0:

```
String node = list.get(0);
```

Then extract the first part by looking for the space

```
String num = node.substring(0,node.indexOf(' '));
```

Although I suggest looking into `HashMaps` for such implementation, which takes Key,Value pairs:

For your example, you will need something like:

```
Map<Long,String> myMap = new HashMap<Long,String>();
myMap.put(number,string);
```

Comment: Thanks @aioobe, you are good in read/compile :), this is the kind of errors you get when writing outside an IDE.

Comment: @asgs, no idea, but me and Sean have the Map suggestion! Maybe someone hates Maps!!

Comment: hahah! I'll remember that quote.. "Maby someone hates Maps" :-))

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a string to that list. x + y, where either x or y is a string produces a string. If you want to have access to the number and the string, you should consider using another type - not a String here. Something like:

```
LinkedList<Pair<Number, String>> list = new LinkedList<Pair<Number, String>();
list.add(new Pair<Number, String>(number, string));
```

This way, to obtain the number, stored in the first element of the list:

```
Pair thePair = list.get(0);
number = (Number)thePair.left;
```

Pair is a class, you can find in Apache Commons: 
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta/org/apache/commons/lang3/Pair.html
(A source for many useful Java classes)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest encapsulating your number and string into a class, like this.

```
public final class Pojo {
    private final Number number;
    private final String string;

    public Pojo(Number number, String string) {
        this.string = string;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void getString() {
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return number + " " + string;
    }
}
```

Then, create your List like this:

```
List<Pojo> list = new LinkedList<Pojo>(); // use generics for compile-time type safety
list.add(new Pojo(42, "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"); // add a Pojo
System.out.println(list.get(0).getNumber());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number+" "+string
```

Acts as a single string, if you want to get the number:

```
list.get(index).split(" ")[0]
```

Even if it works, this is not a clear way to manage a pair of values.
From an object-oriented point of view (and this is the right context :D ), use directly an object:

```
class Pair {
int number;
String str;
}
```

Put your object to the list:

```
Pair pair = new Pair();
pair.number = 1;
pair.str = "hello";
list.add(pair);
```

And get your number:

```
((Pair)list.get(0)).number;
```

Of course you can use class methods and generics to manage all in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

when you are initiating a Linkedlist in java, you should specify the data type that you are going to store in. You haven't done so. As your requirement it should be:

```
LinkedList<int> list=new LinkedList<>();
```

After that you can add your elements:

```
list.add(<number>);
```

Then you can get the first element:

```
list.getFirst();
```

Then you can print that.